# Make Finder window hover above all apps

Tags: macos, finder, productivity, window-manager

I'm looking for a utility that will help me in keeping Finder windows hovering about all apps. Anyone heard of such?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### [afloat](http://infinite-labs.net/afloat/)

.. does exactly what you want.

> Keep windows afloat (heh) on top of all others.

You can pin windows to be always on top of others. This includes all possible windows, not only Finder ones. There does seem to be a hiccup with Finder – you might want to look at [this guide](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/easy-steps-to-solve-mac-window-management-issues-with-afloat/) for more information. Basically it should work in Snow Leopard. For a list of apps that won't work with afloat, see [here](http://infinite-labs.net/kb/afloat/af-app-without-commands.html).

Btw: Another nice feature:

> Show a window's file in the Finder with nothing more than your keyboard.